# Android Studio how to use ActionBarScherlock

Tags: android, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock

**Hello everyone,**

I'm trying to create a project using `ActionBarScherlock` but all the time I experience problems.

I was looking for answers at Stackoverflow but still the problems persist. I create projects into this library; I'm trying to import modules etc.

Still, I got problems like this:

> Error:The SDK Build Tools revision (17.0.0) is too low for project
>   ':actionbarsherlock'. Minimum required is 19.1.0.

What I want is step-by-step instruction how to import this library to work properly.

Comment: why use actionbarsherlock and not the normal actionbar, is actionbarsherlock even still in development?

Comment: i just need to use it :D it dont mean that i want to :D

Answer (score 1):

In your build.gradle:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

dependencies {
  compile 'com.actionbarsherlock:actionbarsherlock:4.4.0@aar'
}
```

Make sure Android Studio is up to date.

Go to android SDK manager and download Android SDK tools Rev. 24.1.2 and Android SDK Platform-tools  Rev. 22

Comment: Still i see this :
Error:The SDK Build Tools revision (17.0.0) is too low for project ':actionbarsherlock'. Minimum required is 19.1.0 

Ofc i have downloaded this tools and higher

Comment: Make sure your SDK tools are up to date, the're an icon on Android Studio, two to the left of the question mark, that'll open up your SDK manager.

Comment: if change dependencies is only think that i do after create project i have too a lot of problems with R. etc

Comment: Set the compile/buildToolsVersion in build.gradle

Comment: done too still problem, i think that problem may be cuz of appcompat v7 which i dont know how to remove